# Why does this bitwise OR return null on a nullable int?

Tags: c#

I essentially have the following:

```
    int? myVal = null;
    myVal |= 1;
    bool stillNull = myVal == null; //returns true
```

Why does this behave this way?  My understanding of bitwise operator/operand behavior is not terribly strong, and I could not find a reason that it wouldn't be treated as a simple assignment in this case.

Comment: Well, what is the value of "quantity I do not know with its lower bit set to one"?  The value can only be "another quantity I do not know". Now, if you'd said `bool? b = null; b |= true; bool b2 = b == null;` then `b2` would be `false` because 'quantity I do not know the truth of OR quantity that is true" is logically true.

Comment: If you want a null value to be treated as 0 (or more generally as `default(T)`) you can use `myNullable =  myNullable.GetValueOrDefault() | 1;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators):

> The predefined unary and binary operators or any overloaded operators
> that are supported by a value type `T` are also supported by the
> corresponding nullable value type `T?`. **These operators,** also known as
> *lifted operators*, **produce `null` if one or both operands are `null`;** otherwise, the operator uses the contained values of its operands to calculate the result.